# Is it true that the circumcenter of an $n$-simplex, when in the simplex's interior, is a convex combination of the midpoints of the edges?

Tags: geometry, spheres, simplex

Is the following true?:

> Suppose we have an $n$-simplex such that the circumcenter of the simplex lies inside.
>
> Is it true that the circumcenter is a convex combination of the midpoints of the edges of the simplex?

In 2D and 3D this seems to be true but I am not sure about higher dimensions. Maybe there is even a counterexample for 2D and 3D.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The simplex has $n+1$ vertices. Apart from $A$ you'd have $n$ other vertices $P$, all "adjacent" to $A$. So there are $n$ possible midpoints of edges $AP$. These form the vertices of an $(n-1)$-simplex, and one would not expect the circumcentre to lie within it. But your simplex has $(n+1)n/2$ edges, each with a midpoint, and they are the vertices of some $n$-dimensional polytope, and it seems an interesting question as to whether the circumcentre lies within that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you are right. I am actually interested in the second question.

Comment: In 2D the midpoints of the edges form a similar simplex, and the circumcenter of the given simplex is the orthocenter of the smaller simplex.